# Table cell width uniform

Tags: css, css-tables

I continue to  develop and quest in css. 
I want to put the table cells all with the same width, and not like how it appears in jsfiddle. I tried to manually put width to the  "th tag" and "td tag" but they are not giving the widths I define.

```
.tablesorter {
margin: -5px 0 0 0;   
table-layout: fixed;
}

 .tablesorter td{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;    
} 

 .tablesorter thead tr { 
 height: 34px;
 color:#082B33;;
 background:#B5E5EF;
text-align: left;
cursor: pointer;   
}
```

The fiddle link is as follows:
https://jsfiddle.net/4j43fdm1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  .tablesorter{
   width:100%;
  }

table tr th, table tr td{
  width:16.6%;
  word-break: break-all;
  }
```

[Click here for demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cj3gbcoa/1/)

Comment: so the break-all breaks the texts in line correct? and what if I have tables with different number of columns ? i have to apply the width: in tr th, differently?