# CSS Table uniform column widths

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to get a table with equal column width without specifying the overall table width and without specifying the individual column widths?

In other words, have every column be the width of the widest column - without knowing in advance the width of that widest column?

(And, I guess I mean without waiting for the table to render, then finding the width of each column, then have JS set the widths of all columns to that largest width).

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915217/table-cell-width-uniform

Comment: Please post the code you have tried. There are at least two ways to interpret your question (html tables, css grid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with `<table>`, but you can do it with `display: grid`.

```css
.a {
  display: inline-block;
}
.a>div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5,1fr);
  gap: 2px;
}
.a>div>div {
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>22</div>
    <div>333</div>
    <div>4444</div>
    <div>55555</div>
    <div>66</div>
    <div>7777</div>
    <div>888888</div>
    <div>99999999</div>
    <div>0000000000</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks much - same approach as previous response but also appreciate the "don't think it can be done in a table".

Answer (score 1):

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>  
</div>
```

An alternative solution to the table could be a CSS grid system. You can solve using CSS grid if you want

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: To be honest, I was not aware of CSS grids.  I'm not sure I want to take the time to convert from a table structure (which otherwise works very well - this is a real table and not just using tables to align things) but helpful to know and appreciated... and I might give it a look and see how hard the conversion would be (this is the main output of a complex dynamic report).

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Does this do what you're after?

Here's what you said you wanted:

> Is there a way to get a table with equal column width without
> specifying the overall table width and without specifying the
> individual column widths?

So my CSS here doesn't specify a table width, nor does it specify **fixed** column widths. It does, however, specify percentage column widths based on the **number of columns** in the table.

The result is a table where all the columns are the same width, and the table is only as wide as it needs to be.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<table class="a">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>333</td>
    <td>4444</td>
    <td>55555</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>66</td>
    <td>7777</td>
    <td>888888</td>
    <td>99999999</td>
    <td>0000000000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```